# How to show that some problem is in NP and that it's NP-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np, subset-sum

I need some help with the following question:

> Recall the *subset sum problem*, which is known to be NP-complete:
>
> *"Given a finite set of natural numbers and a number $n$, decide whether a subset of the given set exists such that the numbers in that subset sum up to $n$."*
>
> We consider the *great subset sum problem*:
>
> *"Given a finite set of natural numbers adding up to $N$ and a number $n > N/2$, decide whether a subset of the given set exists such that the numbers in that subset sum up to $n$."*
>
> a. Show that the great subset sum problem is in NP by giving the notion of certificate and arguing that the certificate can be checked in polynomial time.
>
> b. Show that the great subset sub problem is NP-complete.
>
> *(Hint: extend the set by adding one large number.)*

This was my "proof" but I think it lacks details and I feel it's wrong because I didn't use the hint for part B. Can someone tell me if did something wrong? But please, don't get use too many technical terms as we mainly use text and I might not understand your explanation.

---

**a)** A certificate for the great subset sum problem is a subset of the given set of natural numbers.

Certificate checking is done by adding up the numbers in the subset and comparing the result to the number **n** without forgetting the extra requirement that **n** > $N/2$.

Clearly, if **m** is the size of the original set of numbers (i.e., the size of the input), then the verification requires at most $m-1$ additions, one comparison, and final checking step, so it can be done in $O(m)$.

$O(m)$ because of the following: Adding 2 numbers takes O(1), you have to do that m-1 times. Then do one computation which also takes O(1) and finally do one comparison which also takes O(1), so in total that's O(m).

**b)** From the first part of the exercise it already follows that the great subset-sum problem is in NP.

To show that the great subset-sum problem is NP-complete, it remains to prove that it is NP-hard. The latter we can do by showing a polynomial-time reduction from the subset sum problem to the great subset sum problem.

Let **S** be a set of natural numbers and let **n** be a natural number. Let  $S^\prime$ be obtained from **S** by dividing every number in **S** by **2**; clearly, $S^\prime$ can be obtained by an algorithm whose running time is linear in the size of **S**. Note that **S** has a subset such that the numbers in that subset add up to **n** if, and only if, $S^\prime$ has a subset such that the numbers in that subset add up to **n** where **n** > $N/2$.

So, we have now presented a polynomial-time reduction from the subset-sum problem to the great subset-sum problem. Since the subset sum problem is NP-hard, it follows that the great subset sum problem is NP-hard too.

---

Comment: If you divide all numbers by 2, you also have to divide the target by 2. So you didn't gain anything.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus correct me if i understood you wrong, so i just have to divide n by two and then it's correct?

Comment: Suppose that the numbers are 2,4,6 and the target is 2, which is smaller than 12/2. You suggest dividing everything by 2: the numbers are 1,2,3 and the target is 1. Unfortunately, 1 is still smaller than 6/2.

Comment: Okay i get what you're pointing out. But how adding up a huge number would help? so if i added 800 as a number for your example i will end up with nothing useful? or do i have to choose that big number based on something?

Comment: That's for you to answer. The only way to understand a mathematical topic is to solve questions.

Comment: Is your example considered valid since n should be > 6?

Comment: We need the target to exceed half the sum of all elements.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71524/discussion-between-abdul-malek-altawekji-and-yuval-filmus).

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my answer is correct" questions, as only "yes/no" answers are possible, which won't help you or future visitors. See [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/597/) and [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/519/). Can you edit your post to ask about a specific conceptual issue you're uncertain about? As a rule of thumb, a good conceptual question should be useful even to someone who isn't looking at the problem you happen to be working on. If you just need someone to check your work, you might seek out a friend, classmate, or teacher.

Comment: It's often best to avoid deleting your question after you get an answer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that might be useful to others in the future, and answerers might be taking their time not only to help you but also to advance that mission as well -- deleting your question prevents anyone else from benefiting in the future.  Thank you!

Comment: @D.W. i deleted the question because it's in the assignment for the upcoming week and i didn't want to have an answer but rather a tip but then Xin Yuan Li posted an answer which i can't remove so i don't want the whole class to copy the answer and that's why in the first place i posted the question as an image so that if you google you can't find it but then Yuval Filmus wrote it down and now it's findable. Can you please delete it and re-open it in a week or so?

Comment: I understand, but it's still problematic to use the site in this way.  In the future, if you only want a hint but not a complete answer, make sure you say that in the question.  Also, are you sure you should be posting your homework here?  Make sure you credit the help you got here when you turn in your homework.

Comment: There was an excellent hint in the quoted material. Why didn’t you use that? I mean the solution is basically spelled out for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing a reduction it is important to keep in mind exactly what you are doing. In particular you are trying to reduce *from* a known hard problem (here subset sum, $\mathsf{SS}$) *to* your problem (here great subset sum, $\mathsf{GSS}$) such that yes-instances of the hard problem map to yes-instances of your problem and no-instances map to no-instances.

As mentioned in the comments, if you simply divide each number in $S$ by two (and also divide $n$ by two) you *do not* get an instance of $\mathsf{GSS}$; it might not be the case that $\frac{n}{2} \geq \frac{N}{2}$.

Please think about the problem a bit more before looking at the solution below.

> Let our $\mathsf{SS}$ instance be $S = \{s_1, ..., s_k\}$ with $\sum_{s_i \in S} s_i = N$ and target $n$. We construct the following $\mathsf{GSS}$ instance: $S' = \{s_1, ..., s_k, N\}$ with target $n' = N + n$. Observe that this *is* a $\mathsf{GSS}$ instance since $n' \geq \frac{1}{2}\sum_{s \in S'} s = N$. It remains to show that yes-instances map to yes-instances and no-instances map to no-instances. If some subset $A \subseteq S$ adds up to $n$ then $A \cup \{N\}$ adds up to $N + n$. If not then no subset of $S'$ adds up to $n'$ since $n' > N$ so this subset must contain $\{N\}$ and a subset of $S$ which adds up to $n$.